# What is blocking RuboCop from fixing all auto-correctable offenses?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I have a large code base and am using [RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/) to make it adhere to standards. I've started using [RuboCop v0.90.0](https://rubygems.org/gems/rubocop/versions/0.90.0) this week, and am seeing behaviour that I cannot explain.

When executing `rubocop -x` (for only formatting offenses) to auto-correct offenses, a lot of "auto-correctable" offenses will be noticed but not fixed.

```
$ rubocop -x
...
753 files inspected, 522 offenses detected, 5 offenses corrected, 517 offenses auto-correctable
```

Running `rubocop -x` again will then fix 2 or 3 more offenses, and so on. It is not really practical to fix all offenses this way. Seeing the same behaviour for `rubocop -a`, by the way.

We are also using `rubocop-rails` and `rubocop-rspec`, and have custom RuboCop configuration files to enable and disable Cops.

Things I tried that did not fix this:

- disabled both `rubocop-rails` and `rubocop-rspec`
- also disabled all custom RuboCop configuration files
- running on smaller sets of files (eg `rubocop -x app/models/`)

Can anyone point me in the right direction to try and solve this? (Very hesitant to call this a RuboCop bug as I'm seeing nothing like this in their [Issues](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues) list, and we do have a large and ugly code base.)

#### Edit with some more results

- `rubocop -A` gives me `537 files inspected, 5161 offenses detected, 3876 offenses corrected, 482 offenses auto-correctable` as a result. I would still not expect this "482 offenses auto-correctable" after running with `-A`.
- `rubocop -A --only Layout/SpaceInsideBlockBraces` for example seems to fix all offenses for this Cop, but `rubocop -A --only Layout/LineLength` does nothing at all. That might be something. I have to think about running this for some more Cops and seeing results.
- Nope, `rubocop -A --only Layout/SpaceInsideBlockBraces` only detects 1 new offense every run, fixes that one, and the next run finds a new offense and fixes that one. Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Did you try using `-A` instead? You have a lot of offenses but can you try using the --only option with a couple of them to see if they get corrected?

Comment: @SebastianPalma thanks for your comment! I tried some more runs with the options you mention, but it is all not very conclusive.

Comment: Have you set `AutoCorrect: true` for that cop in your .rubocop.yml file (in your project or in your home folder)?

Comment: Have you searched your entire directory tree for Rubocop configuration files?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. It says 2 offenses are auto-correctable but doesn't auto correct. These are for Layout/LineLength cop. I put Enabled: true, Max: 80, AutoCorrect: true and ran rubocop with -A, --only Layout and none of them are working. May be I should rise a issue.

Comment: Okay, in my case this might be the issue: [1.0 does not add Layout/SpaceInsideBlockBraces and Layout/SpaceInsideHashLiteralBraces excluding files to .rubocop_todo.yml](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/issues/8938). No fix yet, I'll try and see if my issue is the same as that one in a bit.